# Vec operator of matrices stacked vertically and matrix of vec operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two matrices stacked vertically (one of the top of the other):

$  \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{B_1} \\ \boldsymbol{B_2} \end{bmatrix}$.

I want to find the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ that defines the  linear trasformation:

$\boldsymbol{A} vec \left( \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{B_1} \\ \boldsymbol{B_2} \end{bmatrix} \right)= \begin{bmatrix}vec(\boldsymbol{B_1}) \\ vec(\boldsymbol{B_2}) \end{bmatrix} $.

How can I proceed?